# Getting minimum value for three columns group by a single column in a single table

Tags: mysql

I have a single table and my table structure is like this:

```
unique_id     vendor_name      price1     price2     price3    code 

1             Vendor 1         0.0012     0.0014     0.0054     125
2             Vendor 2         0.0015     0.0016     0.0050     125
3             Vendor 3         0.0011     0.0019     0.0088     125
4             Vendor 1         0.0025     0.0024     0.0034     126
5             Vendor 2         0.0043     0.0019     0.0065     126
6             Vendor 3         0.0019     0.0085     0.0082     126
```

I have to fetch the min price for each price column group by code. And my expected output is as follows:

```
Code          price1          price2      price3     vendor for price1      vendor for price 2      vendor for price 3

125           0.0011          0.0014      0.0050     Vendor3                Vendor1                 Vendor 2 
126           0.0019          0.0019      0.0034     Vendor3                Vendor2                 Vendor 1
```

So what would be the MySQL query to fetch records like this? And also I have to make a query to fetch maximum and second highest value from the table and there may be any number of rows with single code.

My data is in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/176c29/1).

In the second highest value case the output should be as:

```
Code          price1          price2      price3     vendor for price1      vendor for price 2      vendor for price 3
125           0.0012          0.0016      0.0054     Vendor1                Vendor2                 Vendor 1 
126           0.0025          0.0024      0.0065     Vendor1                Vendor1                 Vendor 2
```

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: no its not my home work i have to use it in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    data.*,
    v1.vendor_name 'vendor for price1',
    v2.vendor_name 'vendor for price2',
    v3.vendor_name 'vendor for price3'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Code,
            MIN(price1) price1,
            MIN(price2) price2,
            MIN(price3) price3
        FROM
            tbl
        GROUP BY Code
    ) data
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            MIN(vendor_name) vendor_name,
            Code
        FROM
            tbl
        WHERE
            price1 = 
            (
                SELECT
                    MIN(price1)
                FROM
                    tbl t
                WHERE
                    t.Code = tbl.Code
            )
        GROUP BY Code
    ) v1 ON data.Code = v1.Code
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            MIN(vendor_name) vendor_name
            Code
        FROM
            tbl
        WHERE
            price2 = 
            (
                SELECT
                    MIN(price2)
                FROM
                    tbl t
                WHERE
                    t.Code = tbl.Code
            )
        GROUP BY Code
    ) v2 ON data.Code = v2.Code
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            MIN(vendor_name) vendor_name
            Code
        FROM
            tbl
        WHERE
            price3 = 
            (
                SELECT
                    MIN(price3)
                FROM
                    tbl t
                WHERE
                    t.Code = tbl.Code
            )
        GROUP BY Code
    ) v3 ON data.Code = v3.Code
```

Even though the query itself looks pretty big, but the joins are repeated 3 times.

**UPDATE** I updated the query removing `LIMIT` and adding `MIN(vendor_name) vendor_name` instead of `vendor_name`.

Demo 

## Here

OUTPUT

```
| CODE | PRICE1 | PRICE2 | PRICE3 | VENDOR FOR PRICE1 | VENDOR FOR PRICE2 | VENDOR FOR PRICE3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  125 | 0.0011 | 0.0014 | 0.0050 |          Vendor 3 |          Vendor 1 |          Vendor 2 |
|  126 | 0.0019 | 0.0019 | 0.0034 |          Vendor 3 |          Vendor 2 |          Vendor 1 |
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and its working fine, only issue is that it is giving vendor name values only for first row, and for other rows its giving null values for vendor names corresponding to a price

Comment: I think I've noticed what the problem might be and fixed accordingly. Try now :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it

```
SELECT
  vender_prices.code,
  l.price1,
  r.price2,
  m.price3,
  l.vendor_name `Vender1`,
  r.vendor_name `Vender2`,
  m.vendor_name `Vender3`
FROM vender_prices
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               code, vendor_name, vender_prices.price1
             FROM vender_prices
               INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(price1) AS price1 FROM vender_prices GROUP BY vender_prices.code) AS l
                 ON l.price1 = vender_prices.price1
             GROUP BY vender_prices.code
             ) as l ON vender_prices.code = l.code
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               code, vendor_name, vender_prices.price2
             FROM vender_prices
               INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(price2) AS price2 FROM vender_prices GROUP BY vender_prices.code) AS l
                 ON l.price2 = vender_prices.price2
             GROUP BY vender_prices.code
             ) as r ON vender_prices.code = r.code
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               code, vendor_name, vender_prices.price3
             FROM vender_prices
               INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(price3) AS price3 FROM vender_prices GROUP BY vender_prices.code) AS l
                 ON l.price3 = vender_prices.price3
             GROUP BY vender_prices.code
             ) as m ON vender_prices.code = m.code
GROUP BY vender_prices.code
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

OUTPUT

```
| CODE | PRICE1 | PRICE2 | PRICE3 |  VENDER1 |  VENDER2 |  VENDER3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  125 | 0.0011 | 0.0014 | 0.0050 | Vendor 3 | Vendor 1 | Vendor 2 |
|  126 | 0.0019 | 0.0019 | 0.0034 | Vendor 3 | Vendor 2 | Vendor 1 |
```

Comment: Thanks Raheel thanks allot for your help its working fine. One more favour raheel , i have also to pick second highest price like min in other cases. So can you please help me that what changes i make in this query to meet that requirement. Once again thanks allot for your work

Comment: i dont understand your point unless you put some desired output for 2nd highest values

Comment: hi raheel i have updated the requirement in the question for second case with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select table1.vendor_name as vendor_name_for_price1,table2.vendor_name as vendor_name_for_price2, table3.vendor_name as vendor_name_for_price3

from 
table table1, table table2, table table3,
(Select code, min(price1),min(price2),min(price3) from table group by code ) TMP1

where
table1.price1=min(price1) and table1.code=TMP1.code
and
table2.price2=min(price2) and table2.code=TMP2.code
and
table3.price3=min(price3) and table3.code=TMP2.code ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good practice,and I try it a brute method @ first.

```
select 1 as wh,code,min(price1) as price,vendor_name
from(
  select code,price1,vendor_name
  from ForgeRock
  order by code,price1
  )t1
group by code
union all
select 2 as wh,code,min(price2) as price,vendor_name
from(
  select code,price2,vendor_name
  from ForgeRock
  order by code,price2
  )t1
group by code
union all
select 3 as wh,code,min(price3) as price,vendor_name
from(
  select code,price3,vendor_name
  from ForgeRock
  order by code,price3
  )t1
group by code
```

This is very simple and easy method without join,
and I think this is enough for using.
I add a column wh,which you can pivot the result if you want.
But however,you can't get 2nd lowest result using the code above.
There are several method you can reach this goal,
and I suggest you try making partitions like:

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`unique_id` tinyint, `vendor_name` varchar(8), `price1` float(5,4)
    , `price2` float(5,4), `price3` float(5,4),`code` tinyint)
PARTITION BY KEY(code)
PARTITIONS 2;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`unique_id`, `vendor_name`, `price1`, `price2`, `price3`, `code`)
VALUES
(1,'Vendor 1',0.0012,0.0014,0.0054,125),
(2,'Vendor 2',0.0015,0.0016,0.0050,125),
(3,'Vendor 3',0.0011,0.0019,0.0088,125),
(4,'Vendor 1',0.0025,0.0024,0.0034,126),
(5,'Vendor 2',0.0043,0.0019,0.0065,126),
(6,'Vendor 3',0.0019,0.0085,0.0082,126);
```

Well this is a little tricky,but very useful when you don't have so many various values in `code`.
You can get the result just like:

```
select * from
(select code,price1 as price,vendor_name
from ForgeRock partition (p0)
order by price1
Limit 1,1
)t1
union all
select * from
(select code,price1 as price,vendor_name
from ForgeRock partition (p1)
order by price1
Limit 1,1
)t1
union all
select * from
(select code,price2 as price,vendor_name
from ForgeRock partition (p0)
order by price2
Limit 1,1
)t1
union all
select * from
(select code,price2 as price,vendor_name
from ForgeRock partition (p1)
order by price2
Limit 1,1
)t1
union all
select * from
(select code,price3 as price,vendor_name
from ForgeRock partition (p0)
order by price3
Limit 1,1
)t1
union all
select * from
(select code,price3 as price,vendor_name
from ForgeRock partition (p1)
order by price3
Limit 1,1
)t1
```

While I think you can improve my answer obviously,
I'll leave that job to you.